# split words into letter and replace the letters with something else

Tags: c

I got an exercise which says :

> write a program which can separate the  letters from words and then replace the letters with Alpha Bravo Charlie Delta Echo Foxtrot Golf Hotel India Juliet Kilo Lima Mike November Oscar Papa Quebec Romeo Sierra Tango Uniform Victor Whiskey Xray Yankee Zulu (a = Alpha B=bravo etc.) and the numbers with * (1= * 2= ** 3= *** etc.).

Let's say I want to break down the sentence "Hello 2 you!.".

I want my program to return:

```
Hotel Echo Lima Lima Oscar ** Yankee Oscar Uniform!.
```

How do I write a program to do this?

Comment: Use a Map. Should be pretty easy after that.

Comment: @sircodesalot What do you mean by "Map"?

Comment: I think he means a lookup table.

Comment: can you plz explain it a little

Comment: I find difficult to believe *someone* would give you an exercise without explaining the core concepts needed to solve it ...

Comment: You need to do a few things. 1) Read in the sentence. 2) Parse the string into separate words/numbers. 3) For each letter, output their corresponding string (i.e. Y ouputs Yankee). 4) For each number output the amount of stars.

Comment: @Chirality 1) and 2) aren't necessary. You can just read and process one character at a time.

Comment: @melpomene Sure, but typically with larger files you're going to want to read in more than a character at a time.

Comment: @alebianco Why did you change the tag from C to JavaScript??

Answer (score 0):

The program below is only one of many possible takes, and should give you the idea for your solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

char * alphaTable[] = {
"Alpha",
"Bravo",
"Charlie",
"Delta",
"Echo",
"Foxtrot",
"Golf",
"Hotel",
"India",
"Juliet",
"Kilo",
"Lima",
"Mike",
"November",
"Oscar",
"Papa",
"Quebec",
"Romeo",
"Sierra",
"Tango",
"Uniform",
"Victor",
"Whiskey",
"Xray",
"Yankee",
"Zulu",
NULL
};

 void strtoupper(char *s)
 {
   while (*s)
   {
     if ((*s >= 'a') && (*s <= 'z'))
          *s -= ('a'-'A');
     s++;
   }
 }

 char * findMatch(char *table[], char c) 
 {
   int i;
   for(i=0; table[i] != NULL; i++)
   {
       if ( table[i][0] == c) // if first character matches
       {
         return table[i];
       }
   }   

   return NULL;
 }

 int printConvertedText(char *input)
 {
 int i;

 strtoupper(input);   // convert all letters to caps   

 for (i=0;input[i]!=0;i++)
 {
   // take characters from the input string 
    char c = input[i];
   // and find matching first letter in the alphaTable 
    char * result = findMatch(alphaTable,c);
    if(result)
    {
        printf(" %s",result);
    }
    else // NOT A LETTER 
    {
        if (isdigit(c)) // number 
        {
            int num = c-'0'; // a short cut: get a number   
            int j;

             printf(" "); 

            for(j=0;j<num;j++) // nothing printed for 0!
            {
             printf("%s","*");     
            }
        }
        else // everything else is printed as is
        {
             printf("%c",c);                   
        }    
    }
 }

 return 0;
}

int main()
{
  size_t bytes_read  = 0;
  size_t nbytes      = 1000;
  char *my_string;

  // this works for given string: 
  // char input [] = "Hello 2 you!."; 
  // printConvertedText(input);

  puts ("Please enter a line of text: ");
  my_string = (char *) malloc (nbytes + 1); // alocate memory for input

  bytes_read = getline (&my_string, &nbytes, stdin); // get the input

  if (bytes_read == -1)
  {
    puts ("ERROR!\n");
  }
  else
  {
    puts ("You typed:");
    puts (my_string);

    puts ("After conversion:");
    printConvertedText(my_string);

  }

  return 0;
}
```

// Output:

```
Please enter a line of text:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
hello2 you!!.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
You typed:                           
hello2 you!!.

After conversion:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
 Hotel Echo Lima Lima Oscar **  Yankee Oscar Uniform!!.
```

You can run the code [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_c_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMcEJKZmdLdlEyY00)

Comment: first of all thanks for your time. Second what code should I write in order my program to be able to break down any sentence not just Hello 2 you? I mean I want my program to ask the user to write down a sentence .

Comment: @SavvasAnastasiadis The expanded version of the program, asks user to enter his sentence. Is it helpful?